# Data Discrepancies between NodeJS Analytics client and Site

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client

I've been following some of the GitHub resources from: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client

The data being pulled from the API doesn't line up with the data shown on the Analytics site. The data is usually about 10% off in either direction, but sometimes it's very far off. Is this an issue with a known fix?

Using node 14.19.0. Tried with googleapi 88.2.0 first, then updated to 97.0.0 -- neither worked. Also, the raw data from NodeJS is the same as inserted into SQL, not really any data manipulation here.

[NodeJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZrwV.png)

[SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrGGP.png)

[Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xiHI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, leaving my solution if anyone stumbles across this later on.

[This link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics?hl=en#sampling) details how sampling works in Google Analytics. I figured it had something to do with this but changing the parameters didn't work.

Turns out, the filters I was using in the API query was affecting the sample. I removed them and filtered out what I didn't need outside of the call and it turned out fine.